# Evince default dual view

Tags: evince

I like to use dual view for some documents in evince. Recently, evince caught up up to this, and now it opens every single document in dual view. On the flip side, I prefer to use single view for most documents so this is pretty annoying. Is there a way to revert the change? I do not see any default settings corresponding to the indicated behavior.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Evince click `View` → `Dual` (the one with the check mark before) to reenable single view and then go to `Edit` → `Save Current Settings as Default` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to save these settings.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that this also works for saving the preferences of 'odd' vs 'even' pages on the left in the dual document view.