# Can Evince doul view change page combinition?

Tags: pdf, evince

When I turn on dual view in Evince (press D), the 2nd and 3rd page will be showed in one screen. How could I change as 1st and 2nd page in one screen?  [image: this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Evince just click `View`
and, checked enable odd Pages left,

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please check my update answered.

Comment: @abuThank you very much. Perhaps I'm not native English speaker, I just mean, I want the dual view show 1-2 page on one screen. But Evince shows 1 alone, and 2-3 page on one screen.

Comment: @PaulChen Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/143876/evince-default-dual-view

Comment: Sorry again, it is not my problem. My question is WHY dual view left the cover page alone? I don't want the some pages set alone. Great thanks to you!

Comment: Sorry about my bad English, Lol i missing about what's your mean sir, Please check my update answered.

Comment: Perfect, God bless you!